# Javascript fetch-api issue with # or %

Tags: fetch-api

```
const response = await fetch(
        `${ENV().API_BASE}/Panel/Details/PanelId/${
          model.panelId
        }/Password/${model.Password}
        }`,
      );
```

Also if the user inputs in "%%" I get an error saying Json Parse error. Unrecognized token "<".

Does anyone know the best way of passing these symbols in the model.panelpassword?.
Thanks

Comment: I would like to put a frontend validation regex so that we ensure that it sends only valid data to the backend

Comment: so can you please update your post or share how you fixed it ?

Comment: sorry i meant to say i cant figure out how to convert it to a string, all other characters are accepted.

Comment: okay then try to send headers in the fetch method with : 'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

Comment: and also i see you are forgetting the  closed bracket `)`

Comment: i tried this below and i got the same error
const response = await fetch(${ENV().API_BASE}/Bank/Details/Id/${model.Id }/PanelPassword/${model.panelPassword}}`,{ 'Accept': 'application/json', content Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'} );

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass the data into the url using this method
encodeURIComponent